# add icons inside JQ grid cell attr title

Tags: javascript, html, jqgrid, javascript-objects, jqgrid-formatter

I have 2 icons need to show in cell attribute title like below image,
On click of icon need to perform some action.

Design: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLt60.png)

I tried with:

```
colModel: [
                    //{name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 65, align: 'center', sorttype: 'int'},
                    {name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 80, align: 'center', sorttype: 'date',
                        formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {newformat: 'd-M-Y', reformatAfterEdit: true}, datefmt: 'd-M-Y'},
                    {name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 70,
                        cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
                            return 'title="<i class = fa fa-edit></i>"';
                        }}
]
```

On hover of cell not getting font awesome icon, instead of that getting `<i class = fa fa-edit></i>`

Dummy Developed Screen: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY5c8.png)

Used bootstrap 3.3.7 and font awesome 4.7 and Jquery UI css

How to add icons..?

Comment: Did you have included all the needed css and js files that are responsible make font awesome runing?

Comment: Yes.  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). It's unclear which CSS framework you use: jQuery UI, Bootstrap or both. Thus I guess that you use jQuery UI. In the case you need to use [tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) to display the `title` information in another way. For example the code

```js
$grid.tooltip({
    items: "td[title]",
    content: function() {
        var element = $(this),
            title = element.attr("title");
        if (title) {
            return '<span class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-edit"></span>' +
                title;
        }
    }
});
```

be used in the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yvbt6w54/60/. The results looks like on the picture below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Oleg. But i can't click on the edit icon(Font Awesome). On click of that need to perform some action.

Comment: Kindly check can we do?

Comment: @Pavan: Tooltips are exist mostly for **displaying** some additional information and not for showing an alternative User Interface for changing the page. In general everything is possible, but you will have to implement the special requirements yourself. The standard interface have editing buttons if you use `formatter: "actions"`. The buttons are parts of the row, which need be editing. The tooltip is absolute positioned div over the grid. You have to save in the tooltip some reference to the row (rowid, for example) and bind your custom `click` handler where you start `editRow` method on row